# Allow self-signed certificates for HTTPS wrapper

Tags: php, https, certificate, self-signed

Basically i have this:

```
function request($url) {
    return file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => true,
            "allow_self_signed" => false,
        )
    )));
}

request("https://[A]");
request("https://[B]");
```

Where [A] is some URL on a server with a "real" certificate and [B] is something on one with only a self-signed certificate.

With [A] it works fine, with [B] i get this:

```
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
```

Which is a rather unfortunate error message that should have been something like "server certificate verification failed", but fine...

Now i thought: "ok, [B] is my test system - i don't care for the certificate" and changed the context into this:

```
"verify_peer" => false,
"allow_self_signed" => true,
```

It [should](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) now accept any server certificate, even my self signed one. But it's still the same behavior - [A] works, [B] doesn't. Why?

---

Btw: I know that it works well with the curl extension, but i want to beat this without it.

Comment: Please define *"With [A] it works fine"* ... because neither of those should ever work. You haven't specified a `"cafile"` or `"capath"` to tell PHP what CA certs to use for peer verification and you've disallowed self-signed certificates. Neither [A] nor [B] could ever connect successfully if you're indeed using the exact code shown here.

Comment: PHP [already defaults](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.verify-peer) to `verify_peer = true` and `allow_self_signed = false` without specifying them.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me. Good luck.

```
$context = [ 'http' => [ 'method' => 'GET' ], 'ssl' => [ 'verify_peer' => false, 'allow_self_signed'=> true ] ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$resp = file_get_contents('https://site/', false, $context);
```

Comment: This also apparently works if you have no SSL at all!  I tried it on a MAMP server with no SSL setup whatsoever, and it worked.  Great if you just need to get things moving on a dev server :)

Comment: I had to add the option `'verify_peer_name' => false` to get self-signed-cert to work

Answer (score 2):

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'       => true,
        'allow_self_signed'=> true
    )
);
$sslContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
```

file_get_contents("https://...., false, $sslContext);

the above works fine

Comment: I think `verify_peer` should be set to `false`, if you use a SSL MITM proxy.